# Issue in creating a raw bitcoin transaction(single input and single output)

Tags: bitcoin

When signing a transaction,I have copied the scriptPubKey from previous referenced transaction (for script field in input) and appended the hash-type.

Then in the original transaction,I have replaced the script with scriptSig and removed the hash-type. 
[Raw Transaction](https://coinb.in/?verify=0100000001f580570889d0bc5c4babee1a9b2171d26a5bb922a73d28f5ba26d0b7fd96286c020000008930440220500afddb14f16a4bcc67863ba98db6a98aa1fd806b13f3cf53d570ddcdb504f6022072b6c891ad84381796bd931444eb2ad68ebf0755005c5663398e312ab28cedc10141043f9560df57119b9f87e88cea1a478eeff36b641d232027a96b9ffe46673600b0af047ab6f945d8a0fccd7c0c257ebb387945802da522a0c019ea5ee1dfc9397cffffffff0180380100000000001976a9142be2f3ec86f0d670d1a18139caea5eb1893192bf88ac00000000#verify).

But,when I check the transaction is [coinb.in](https://coinb.in/?verify=0100000001f580570889d0bc5c4babee1a9b2171d26a5bb922a73d28f5ba26d0b7fd96286c020000008930440220500afddb14f16a4bcc67863ba98db6a98aa1fd806b13f3cf53d570ddcdb504f6022072b6c891ad84381796bd931444eb2ad68ebf0755005c5663398e312ab28cedc10141043f9560df57119b9f87e88cea1a478eeff36b641d232027a96b9ffe46673600b0af047ab6f945d8a0fccd7c0c257ebb387945802da522a0c019ea5ee1dfc9397cffffffff0180380100000000001976a9142be2f3ec86f0d670d1a18139caea5eb1893192bf88ac00000000#verify),it says that the transaction is not signed.
The code I'm using to generate is inspired from [Ken Shirriff's blog](http://www.righto.com/2014/02/bitcoins-hard-way-using-raw-bitcoin.html) and [Shlomi's video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjCswCRBHdc&list=PLH4m2oS2ratf2N7l-LSU4qeeGwtbhzfWc)

My version of the code can be found [here](https://github.com/shravan-shandilya/bitcoin-basics)

Snippet which populates the transaction is here:

```
    def get_real_transaction(self,account):
        sigscript = self.generate_sig_script(account)
        self.real_transaction = ""
        self.real_transaction = (
                    self.version
                    + self.txn_inputs_count
                    + self.txn_inputs[0]["output_hash"]
                    + self.txn_inputs[0]["output_index"]
                    + self.txn_inputs[0]["sigScriptBytes"]
                    + self.txn_inputs[0]["sigScript"]
                    + self.txn_inputs[0]["sequence"]
                    + self.txn_outputs_count
                    + self.txn_outputs[0]["value"]
                    + self.txn_outputs[0]["scriptPubKeyBytes"]
                    + self.txn_outputs[0]["scriptPubKey"]
                    + self.locktime
                )
        return self.real_transaction
```

Entire transaction.py is [here](https://github.com/shravan-shandilya/bitcoin-basics/blob/master/transaction.py)

Any guidance/hints will be extremely helpful.

Comment: Can you add your scripts or raw transactions here? It's hard to follow or to tell where what fails.

Comment: @5chdn Added the snippet and the link to the whole file.